# Simplify UIView animation if/else

Tags: swift, swift3, uiview, uiviewanimation

A lot of callbacks and methods in the iOS UIKit library have an `animated` boolean, that says whether an action should be animated, or just set.

One such example is this method:

```
UITableViewCell.setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
```

Let's say I want to change the `textLabel` text color and the cell's background color on selection. I currently do something such as this:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    let bgColor = !selected ? UIColor.clear : UIColor.blue
    let textColor = !selected ? UIColor.black : UIColor.white             

    if !animated {
        self.textLabel?.textColor = textColor
        self.backgroundColor = bgColor
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
            self.textLabel?.textColor = textColor
            self.backgroundColor = bgColor
        }            
    }        
}
```

Very simply, I work out the new colour values, then apply them.

The frustrating part here is that I have to check if we're animating, and if we are wrap the setters in a animation block. This feels really ugly and if you're doing more than just changing background colors, it get's even worse.

I'm sure this has been solved elegantly by others, so I was wondering how you guys (and gals) do it?

Comment: You can encapsulate them in a method and just call that method inside `setSelected`.

Comment: Doesn't look ugly to me. I can read the code and easily understand what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Make a func to handle whatever you want to change, For example,

```
    func updateTheme(selected: Bool) {
        self.textLabel?.textColor = !selected ? UIColor.clear : UIColor.blue
        self.backgroundColor = !selected ? UIColor.black : UIColor.white
    }
```

and just call that in your main func

```
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: selected ? 0.1 : 0) {
            self.updateTheme(selected: selected)
        }        
    }
```

Or

```
   override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    if !animated {
        updateTheme(selected: selected)
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
            self.updateTheme(selected: selected)
        }            
    }        
}
```

Comment: So with your first example, you're saying that if I set the duration to zero, then it skips the animation and just set's them? I did consider this, but was worried about the overhead of starting an animation block needlessly, but I guess that's micro-optimisation at it's finest?

Comment: Pretty sure there is overhead but a single animation call like this wouldn't hurt. If you are really picky you can go with the second option. The idea is taking out the repeating codes into a function and use it.